# Отменить коммит git add

Tags: git

Прошу вашей помощи!

Работаю над большим проектом, после git clone некоторое время работал, а далее сделал "git add ." - отследил все файлы и впоследствии - закоммитил, после этого делал некоторое количество коммитов и пушей.

Можно ли отменить действие команды "git add .", чтобы я добавлял в коммит и пуш только те файлы и папки, что мне нужны вручную? 
Сейчас в "git status" мне уже не отображаются все файлы (как мне хотелось бы), а только новые/исправленные.

Изначально когда мы клонируем проект, а потом присоединяемся введя **git status**
увидим

```
    файл №1 проекта
    файл №2 проекта
    файл №3 проекта
    файл №4 проекта
    файл №5 проекта
    и т.д
```

если введем **git add .**

Все эти файлы будут отслеживаться, коммититься и пушиться. 
Вот я совершил такую оплошность добавить все, откоммитил и запушил.
Если я введу **git status** сейчас, то увижу:

```
    Файлик из огромной системы который я делал вчера
    Файлик из огромной системы, который я делал сегодня
```

А хотелось бы, видеть вот это:

```
        файл №1 проекта
        файл №2 проекта
        файл №3 проекта
        файл №4 проекта
        файл №5 проекта
        Файлик из огромной системы который я делал вчера
        Файлик из огромной системы, который я делал сегодня
        и т.д
```

Comment: Вы и сразу можете не все файлы добавлять, а только нужные: `git add filename`

Comment: git status всегда показывает только новые/измененные файлы. Зачем вам видеть все?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что вы хотите получить? Может быть, вы хотите все изменения с момента клонирования по-другому закоммитить? Например, выбрать конкретные файлы?

Comment: Вы хотите в `git status` видеть **вообще все** файлы или только все которые вы поменяли после клонирования репозитория?

Comment: «Изначально когда мы клонируем проект, а потом присоединяемся введя git status увидим» — тут мы увидим только то, что уже поменялось. Все файлы проекта эта команда никогда не показывает. Наверное, вы что-то перепутали.

Comment: Попробую другой вопрос. Вы этот список файлов хотите увидеть чтобы что? Что вы узнаете из этого списка?

Comment: А команда `git status` показывает только те файлы, которые вы поменяли И пока что не закоммитили. И всё. А чтобы увидеть все файлы есть `ls` или `find`. Но наверняка вы не хотите видеть списком все файлы огромного проекта. Что именно вы хотите увидеть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git reset <file> #резетим конкретный файл
git reset #резетим усе
```

Comment: Я уже сделал git commit и git push.

Comment: Если сейчас ввести "git status", то увижу недавно отредактированные файлы, но не весь проект целиком (чего я хотел бы)

Comment: @fer0m Это неправильная хотелка. Представьте, что у вас в проекте 2000 файлов. Зачем вам нужен этот список? весь проект целиком смотрят в файловом менеджере.

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня прямо сейчас в проекте 10159 файлов :)

Comment: @fer0m а какая цель видеть все файлы? Попробуйте Sourcetree, мне кажется, это то что Вам подойдет)

Comment: Да, вы правы, я неправильно понял, "что мне нужно". Все решается git reset